# 1 in superscript converts to tt

Tags: richtextarea, formatting, inputrichtext

I'm trying to add '1' in superscript to input:

[image]

but '1' is displayed as a 'tt'

[image]

What is the way to add '1' in superscript to be shown properly?

Comment: weird - works for me using `¹`